# How to find the Householder transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Assume $x=(1,0,4,6,3,4)^T$. Find a Householder transformation and a positive number $\alpha$ such that $Hx=(1,\alpha,4,6,0,0)^T$.

I'm sorry that I don't know how to start with this problem. A Householder transformation has the form $H=I-2ww^T$, where $w$ is a unit vector. It seems it keeps the length of the vector it acts on. So, should $\alpha$ be equal to $5$ or $-5$? And how to find matrix $H$? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what to do if you were given just the vector $(6,3,4)^\top$?

Comment: @J.M. I'm sorry for replying so late, I had worked it out. :)

Comment: @Amzoti Sorry for replying so late. Now I know the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since Householder preserve the norm, $\left\| {x} \right\|=\left\| {Hx} \right\|$ and we can choose $\alpha$ to be 5. Let $v=x-y=(0,-1,0,0,3,4)^T$, then $w=\frac{v}{\left\| {v} \right\|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}(0,-1,0,0,3,4)$ and $H=I-2ww^T$

Comment: There's a bit of a mistake here, in that with $\alpha = 5$, the difference $v = x-y = (0,-5,0,0,3,4)^T$.  The idea is correct.